Robust Application for Analyzing Plots with Primary y-axis Bars and Secondary y-axis Scatter
I am looking for a robust application to analyze plots that typically have a primary y-axis with bars (or stacked bars) and a secondary y-axis with scatter points.
Here are some examples of common plots. The application should be robust enough to capture data from a high variability of similar plots automatically and accurately.
plot_1
plot_2
Does anyone know of an application or method that performs well for this task?
I tried using Google Deplot, a Visual Question Answering model, but the performance was very poor. Additionally, I had difficulty converting the output to a pandas DataFrame efficiently.
